# I have two scripts of code and i want to import just one specific line from one into the other. How do i do it?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, import

I want to import one specific line of code from one script into another. I don't want the new code to run the entire script just that one line. How do I do that?

e.g. `from brcus import value`

where value is equal to a number in the completed script and I want to import that number into the new script, and that line of code in the old script is: "value=500"

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you import any python module or package and you use some function or value from that module it is not run all the script at once.

You can do it like that.

1. new script: - new.py
2. old script:- old.py

## if it's in same directory..

```
from old import value

a = value
```

Comment: can you please post your 2 script here, so we can analyse it and help you

Answer (score 0):

I would not recommend your approach for extracting a variable. You should instead have a look at actual data exchange formats e.g. [json](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON) or [xml](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML). 
These are designed to hold and make accessible key-value pairs for programs while being (to some extend) human readable.
Parsers for these formats and many more are available.

Answer (score 0):

if you import with the command

```
from package import value
```

the value will come to your new code as being part of it

E.g

Source.py

```
value = 500
other = 400
```

Destiny.py

```
from Source import value
print (value)
>>500
```

Destiny.py

```
from Source import value
print (other)
>>NameError: name 'other' is not defined
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest moving the part you want to import to a separate module and importing it to all modules it's used in

my_var.py

```
 text = "Hello"
```

test.py

```
from my_var import text

def hello_friend(friend_name)
    print(text + " " + friend_name)
```

main.py

```
from my_var import text

print(text)
```

You may also set an environmental variable and check it's value in the module you are importing

test.py

```
import os

if os.environ['only_new_str'] != str(True):
    print("new_str is not calculated yet")
new_str = "Hello world"
if os.environ['only_new_str'] != str(True):
    print("new_str calculated")
```

main.py

```
import os
os.environ['only_new_str'] = str(True)
import test

print(test.new_str)
```